# Default color of the cosmo shinytheme

Tags: r

May I know what is the default color/ color code of the below image. I got in cosmo shiny theme.I tried with #f5f5f5 . But there is a slight difference between these? Can anyone please help

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using paint.net colorpicker tool it says the color code is: `#ecf0f5`